# Why is this python code using eval function not producing an error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner in python. Found this while solving exercise in the book Think Python. In this code eval_loop function iteratively prompts the user, takes the resulting input and evaluates it using eval, and prints the result.
It should continue until the user enters 'done', and then return the value of the last expression it evaluated. My doubt is:

Eval must have a string as its argument, but this code works even when we input non string like 5+4, it prints 9. Since we are not converting the input into a string anywhere, Please tell me how is it not producing an error?

```
def eval_loop():
    result=0
    while True:
        s = input('>>>')
        if s == 'done':
            break
        result = eval(s)
        print(result)
    print(result)


eval_loop()
```

**Update:**

OK I get it now, the function input returns a string. But now I have one more doubt:

If input function returns a string then why does it produce an error when I give input as - hello, without any inverted commas around it. It gives NameError: name 'hello' is not defined. If input returns a string shouldn't hello be converted to a string too?

Someone please help me out, this is getting very confusing. :(

Comment: `input` returns a string.

Comment: in python 2 it also works since `eval` is included in `input`

Comment: 5+4 works because `eval` evaluates the expression... I'd recommend `simpleeval` instead (external package) which doesn't have any security issues...

Comment: @Aran-Fey if input function returns a string then why does it produce an error when I give input as - hello, without any inverted commas around it. It gives NameError: name 'hello' is not defined. If input returns a string shouldn't hello be converted to a string too?

Comment: Sorry but I honestly don't know how I can explain this.

Comment: @preetikamondal - input `hello` gets converted to a string from `input()`, but when you try to `eval()` the string you're evaluating it as a variable (e.g. `eval("hello")`) and since you don't have a `hello` variable defined you get the error.

Comment: @preetikamondal - "inverted commas", you mean you surround your input in single quotes? Well then you tell Python its a string (equivalent to `eval("'hello'")` so it doesn't try to find a variable with such name. Think of `eval()` as if you were actually typing the code - if you type in your code `'hello'` nothing will happen (it's a string literal so it will just be ignored since its not assigned to anything) but if you type `hello` it will attempt to find a variable named `hello` and raise a `NameError`.

Answer (score 0):

eval() serve a evaluate a string as a python expression

```
print eval("3 + 2")
#5
a = 9
print eval("a == 9")
#true
```

and you can also use raw_input() instead of input() for reading a string